# What is the correct mapping type in model class for integer16, 32 and 64?

Tags: ios, core-data

I get the following error message:

CoreData: error: Property 'type' is a scalar type on class 'Time' that does not match its Entity's property's scalar type.  Dynamically generated accessors do not support implicit type coercion.  Cannot generate a getter method for it.

I think the problem is, that the type NSInteger of my attribute "Type" does not match with the integer 32 type of my Core data data model.

But what is the correct data type?

Comment: Likely should be the reference type NSNumber rather than the value type NSInteger.

Answer (score 17):

The correct types would be`int16_t`, `int32_t`, `int64_t` etc.

Comment: For reference if using Swift the equivalents are Int16, Int32, Int64, etc.  The full list can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/NumericTypes.html)